# How to join two php variables

Tags: php, mysql

Look guys i want to join two php codes into one.
Here is the first code.

```
$add = makeimageadd($compainids,$r['id'],$publisher_ad_id);
```

And this one is second

```
$add = $row['defaultcode'];
```

I am looking to add both codes under $add variable is that possible?

Comment: And what do you mean by "join"? Do you want that the output of the function and the content of that variable will be together in 1 string?

Comment: It's not queries - it's variables, so you can concatenate them.

Comment: What has this to do with mysql?

Comment: I want both codes under $add . is that possible?

Comment: When i am using $add = makeimageadd($compainids,$r['id'],$publisher_ad_id); $add = $row['defaultcode']; together then it won't work for me.. is there any solution to use both of them in one code/?

Comment: The function os $add is almost same of both file.. but contents are different. if we can join both code then it will show 2 results that what i want

Comment: see @thomas when you write the above code all it does is replace one value with another. what is the o/p in both cases and what you want as the o/p would be helpful to help you

Comment: How hard is it to explain properly what you want

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`$add .= $row['defaultcode'];` This should make it done

Comment: what exactly is that you need .? like whats the output of first and second and what you want ?

Comment: That's exactly what OP was asking, +1 from me.